# How to avoid multiple workers running all at once when constraint is met?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I have multiple workers queued with constraint set to NetworkType.CONNECTED. This makes sure that all changes in my app gets enqueue and sent off to the server when the user is connected to a network.

I have recently had some downtime on my server because there is a LOT of web requests sent to the server all at once, I believe this comes from some users that have a lot of queued work requests (Eg. been offline for a long time).

Can I avoid that all the queued work requests being handled at the same time? Is there a way of delaying or spread the work requests over time when the constraint is met?

```
val myConstraints = Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use initial delays for your WorkRequests: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder#setInitialDelay(kotlin.Long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Another way is to use a PeriodicWorkRequest which dequeues and uploads a few of your requests each time it runs.

Comment: Thanks SumirKodes, initial delays would only delay worker from being enqueued, not actually when the worker is being handled, no? I still want the workers being handled immediately if there is a connected network.

Comment: Same with the other solution, it would delay requests with at least 15 minutes each time since minimum interval of Periodic work is 15 minutes.